# Matching the First Character on Each Line (UNIX egrep)

Tags: regex, macos, unix, grep

I'm looking to match and return just the first character from each line in a plain-text UTF-8 encoded file using in a UNIX terminal using egrep. I presumed that the following egrep command with a simple RegEx would produce the desired result:

```
egrep -o "^." FILE.txt
```

However, the output appears to be matching and returning *every* character in the file; that is, it is behaving as if the command were:

```
egrep -o "." FILE.txt
```

Similar results occur with the following command,

```
egrep -o "^[a-z]" FILE.txt
```

namely, the results act as if the RegEx "[a-z]" were supplied (i.e., every lowercase ASCII character in the range a-z is matched).

Commands in which just one specific alphanumeric characters ist supplied seem, as expected, to return every line that begins with the specific character, e.g.,

```
egrep -o "^1" FILE.txt
```

or
    egrep -o "^T" FILE.txt

return all lines beginning with "1" or "T", respectively.

I have tried pasting the entirety of the file into a RegEx tester, such as at https://regexr.com/, and the expression "^." indeed behaves as expected, so I don't think that my file has any further whitespace characters that could be interfering.

Is there some other behavior of the line-beginning metacharacter "^" with egrep that could be causing this problem?

Comment: Which platform/grep is this? It works as expected on GNU/Linux.

Comment: This is on OS X 10.12.6.

Comment: OK, I can reproduce this on BSD grep. Definitely unexpected behavior, will have to look closer. Btw, to print the first char on each line you can simply use `cut -c1 file` instead of grep.

Comment: Can you tell me what's the output of your `grep --version`?

Comment: Yes: egrep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Comment: The my answer below is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a known bug](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201650) in BSD `grep` and GNU `grep` 2.5.1-FreeBSD (also discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352977/why-does-this-bsd-grep-result-differ-from-gnu-grep)).

In `-o` mode, `^` anchor isn't handled properly (reported [here](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201650#c3), patched [here](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=172418&action=diff)):

```
$ echo abc | bsdgrep -o "^."
a
b
c
```

GNU `grep` on Linux behaves as expected:

```
$ echo abc | grep -o "^."
a
```

---

Related to what you are trying to achieve here (print the first character of *every* line), `grep` is an overkill. A simple `cut` would suffice:

```
$ echo abc | cut -c1
a
```